# Navigation bar on iPhone popover

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, popover

I don't ask for a lot out of life, but I'd give a lot to know how to get a navigation bar on this popover:

[image]

Here's my storyboard:

[image]

And here's my code presenting the popover:

```
    @IBAction func doButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = PopViewController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 260,height: 300)
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        if let pres = vc.presentationController {
            pres.delegate = (self as UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate)
        }
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
        if let pop = vc.popoverPresentationController {
            pop.sourceView = (sender as! UIView)
            pop.sourceRect = (sender as! UIView).bounds
            pop.backgroundColor = vc.view.backgroundColor
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

*(Thanks to @matt, BTW, for the above code!)*

I've searched high and low on Google yet haven't found an answer that I could understand. I tried to add the `nav bar` in Storyboard, but no dice--the only element that would accept it was the `prototype cell` in the `table view`.

Please don't redirect to something written 7 years ago--I've already read most of them, and I'm using Swift now. Certainly, I may have overlooked a clear answer, and I'll be humble and contrite if that's the case. But meantime, I'd sure appreciate some help if ya got it!

Thanks!

Comment: You could try embedding `PopViewController ` into `UINavigationController` and then present the navigationController instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your right tableview controller to a navigation controller with a tableViewController root. The navigation Controller gets an identifier : "navigation".

[image: right nav controller]

[image]

Now you can change the first code of doButton function, and keep the rest.

```
 @IBAction func doButton(_ sender: Any) {

let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigation") as! UINavigationController


    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 260,height: 300)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    if let pres = vc.presentationController {
        pres.delegate = (self as UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate)
    }
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
    if let pop = vc.popoverPresentationController {
        pop.sourceView = (sender as! UIView)
        pop.sourceRect = (sender as! UIView).bounds
        pop.backgroundColor = vc.view.backgroundColor
    }
}
```

finally , you will get the nav bar in your popover.

Comment: Thanks very much, amigo! For some reason, I find the whole popover trip to be the most vexing thing I've come across in iOS. Core Data is a piece of cake by comparison... :)